# Disabled input value in mailto protocol

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, mailto

I need to send a form via email and in this form there is a text input that needs to be disabled so that it cannot be modified.
Can i put it's value in the email or do i have to enable?

Here is the code:

`Punteggio attuale:&nbsp;
<input type="text" disabled id="punteggio_" name="Punteggio registrato ">
<button type="button" onclick="punti()">Aggiorna punteggio</button>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use the `readonly` attribute:

```
<input readonly value="whatever" />
```

But yes, to have its value be submitted the input must not be `disabled`, since a disabled input is considered 'unsuccessful.'

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form disabled fields arn't POSTEd by default in most browsers.

You could circuvent this though by doing this,

```
$("form").submit(function(){
     $(":disabled").prop("disabled",false);
     return true;
});
```

This exampel is using jQuery. but you could do it in plain javascript aswell.

Or you could use the ***readonly*** attribute instead